# Tomb of Horrors in D&D 4.0?

Tags: dnd-4e

Are there any resources on the web or in print about running or converting the classic adventure 'Tomb of Horrors' in D&D 4.0?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's the hardcover [Tomb of Horrors](http://wizards.com/dnd/Product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/253850000) superadventure, which is readily available in stores. It's not a strict conversion, however -- more of an update. Instead of being one adventure, it's a series of interlinked short adventures which are intended to take place over the course of a group's career.

Earlier this summer, WotC sent out a pure conversion to people who'd registered for the [DM Rewards](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/event.aspx?x=dnd/4new/event/dmrewards) program. It's a superb product: it retains the trap-oriented focus of the original, and it's far more deadly than I would have expected from a trap-oriented 4e dungeon. Unfortunately, these rewards are a one-time thing and it probably won't be sent out again. I'm sure it's available on EBay at fairly high prices.

Comment: Reading about missing out on a bonus like an original ToH update to 4e is easily the best advertisement that I could imagine for the DM rewards program.

Comment: I've read both the rewards ToH and the superadventure. The Conversion is amazingly true to the original changing perhaps 2 or 3 minor things and 1 not so important major thing. The Supderadventure is more of a campeign adventure inspired by toH, ToH itself is merely background fluff for it.